# Undefined method `reset_counters' for Mongoid 3.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid3, counter-cache

I just updated my mongoid to version 3.1.6, so that I could use the [reset_counters](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/CounterCache/ClassMethods:reset_counters) method to keep track of my model relations. But just as I did before the gem update I still get this error:

```
undefined method `reset_counters' for Mongoid::Persistence::Atomic::Operation:Module
```

In my Gemfile I have this version:

```
gem 'mongoid', '3.1.6'
```

And Gemfile.lock states:

```
mongoid (3.1.6)
  activemodel (~> 3.2)
  moped (~> 1.4)
  origin (~> 1.0)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
```

Here is the model that should update the counters:

```
class Presentation
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :operation, :inverse_of => :presentations, :counter_cache => true

  after_save :update_counter

  def update_counter
    self.operation_id_change.each do |e|
      Operation.reset_counters(e, :presentations) unless e.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the model where the counter field is:

```
class Operation
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :presentations_count, type: Integer

  has_many :presentations, :inverse_of => :operation, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Documntation says that it has been available since version 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just have a namespace problem. If you look at the error closely:

```
undefined method ... for Mongoid::Persistence::Atomic::Operation:Module
```

you'll see that it is complaining about not being able to find `reset_counters` in `Mongoid::Persistence::Atomic::Operation`, not `Operation`. And if you look at the 3.1.6 source, you'll find `Operation` in [`lib/mongoid/persistence/atomic/operation.rb`](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v3.1.6/lib/mongoid/persistence/atomic/operation.rb).

If you specify the fully qualified name for your `Operation`:

```
def update_counter
  self.operation_id_change.each do |e|
    ::Operation.reset_counters(e, :presentations) unless e.nil?
  # ^^
  end
end
```

then it will call `reset_counters` on the right `Operation` module.